# How to implement a tabular report reader app in cocoa, with disclosure triangles to control what is shown?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an app that creates reports of `hierarchical` tabular data.

- There is some introductory test followed by several top-level (call
  this `level-A`) records
- each having several subordinate records (`level-B`),
- which each has several subordinate records (`level-C`),

finished with some summary text. To show all the record levels in a text file would be a bit of a mess. It would be much cleaner to have a reader that looks like `TextEdit`, but has disclosure triangles next to the records, so the user can control which subordinate records are displayed or hidden.
 The reader could treat each record as simply a line of text, already formatted by the program that created the records, so it would not need any information about the records contents.

Thanks

Comment: Is NSOutlineView what you are looking for?

Comment: I had thought NSOutlineView a poor fit since the report data is not strictly tabular - There is introductory text and each category of data has one line of header that describes the fields. The data itself is wide. Having given it a try, and changing the report format, it can be made to work and look deliberate. Lowering the NSOutlineView.interCellSpacing to -3.0 will give the same spacing as TextEdit.